# HTML Overlay Issues

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am stuck on a HTML overlay issue. My page have a overlay container. It blocks the clicking of the dropdown behind it. I tried to set a very high z-index for the dropdown, but it doesn't work.

Fiddle for my issue:

```
> https://jsfiddle.net/ao4dLp3g/2/
```

Can I get some help? I want to have the original click behavior of dropdown. Is there a way to exclude the dropdown element from the overlay.

It may not be a good idea to create separate overlay containers to cover the rest of area since I may have many elements to exclude.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to hide the dropdown or dropdown button with overlay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the `position` property of the button to `relative`, you can set its `z-index` to be higher than the `z-index` of your overlay.

```
#dropdownMenuButton{
  z-index:1001;
  position:relative;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u0p5fv8t/